# Laravel orderBy with same value result keep changing

Tags: php, laravel

I've try to sort my result within the `updated_at` value. Because I seed the value all the `updated_at` value is same:

```
//     Amount Table
-----------------------------------------------------
| id       |   amount           |  updated_at       |
+----------+--------------------+-------------------+
| 1        | 232319             |2016-02-02 13:17:29|  
| 2        | 232319             |2016-02-02 13:17:29|
| 3        | 100000             |2016-02-02 13:17:29|
| 4        | 231111             |2016-02-02 13:17:29|
| 5        | 12345              |2016-02-02 13:17:29|
+----------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

The problem is everytime I query :

```
 $lists = Amount::orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->lists('id')->toArray();
```

I expect the result to be like this: `[1,2,3,4,5]` but it appear the result is sometime like that but sometime `[2,3,1,4,5]`. it keep randoming the result.

As far as i know, yes i can put another `orderBy` statement to the query, but isn't it suppose to be default it will order by the `id`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are only ordering by updated_at which appear to all have the same value. If you want consistency, include a second column

```
$lists = Amount::orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->lists('id')->toArray();
```